# Drools Artificial Intelligence

Tags: drools

How good is drools if I have to use it to do a artificial intelligence module which can monitor  different software modules on the production box.
If any good java tools to implement AI modules plz do suggest

Answer (score 2):

Drools does not really do "artificial intelligence" as in machine learning.  What drools provides is extremely efficient execution of if/then conditional logic that you, the developer, write.  Drools allows you to write these rules in different dialects (java, mvel, your own custom domain specific language) and then uses the rete algorithm to efficiently fire the rules based on input data you pass into its knowledgebase.

Based on your question it appears to me that you really don't need artificial intelligence to monitor modules on a production box.  What you really need is an event driven architecture that can monitor the boxes and then based on some set of rules raise events to interested parties.  You could create something like this using drools, but remember that there are tons of products (even free ones) that already do this.